# First class object is modified when doing a addition

Tags: c++, class

The code below, which is giving a correct output of the addition, changes **x** value of the first object **b** after doing it.

```
class numbers{
public:
    int x;
    numbers(int i1){
        x = i1;
    }
    numbers operator+ (numbers num){
        x = x + num.x;
        return(x);
    }
};

int main(){
    numbers a (2);
    numbers b (3);
    numbers c (5);
    numbers d (7);
    cout << a.x << b.x << c.x << d.x << endl; // returns 2357
    numbers final (100); //this value won't be shown
    final = a+b+c+d; 
    cout << a.x << b.x << c.x << d.x << endl; // returns 5357
    cout << final.x; //returns 17 (2+3+5+7)
    system("pause");
}
```

The question is, how does this addition class works exactly? I mean, why is **x** from object **a** modified?
I though only **x** from **final** object would be modified.

Thanks :)

Comment: Change your constructor to `explicit numbers(int)` and you should get a better diagnostic about what's going on...

Comment: Try making your `operator +` const.

Comment: This code is a good example of how you should *never* implement `operator+`. People expect `+` to be a binary operation that does not change the operands, so unless there are very good reasons to do otherwise, you should comply with that expectation.

Comment: the function `operator+` returns a `numbers`, so why are you returning an `int`?, is this really compiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to operator+ is just like any other member function call. `a + b` translates to `a.operator+(b)`. So the line `x = x + num.x;` in this case is actually assigning to `a.x`. To achieve what you want you need to instead populate a new numbers with the new value i.e.

```
numbers operator+ (numbers num) const {
    return numbers(x + num.x)
}
```

Also note the const - which would have given you a compile error when you made that mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the quick easy solution :) but I still have a doubt. b+c should be translated to `b.operator+`, shouldn't it? why isn't `b.x` or `c.x` value modified?

Comment: a+b+c is translated to (a+b)+c i.e. a.operator(b).operator(c). i.e. the temporary returned by a+b becomes 'this' in the second addition

Comment: But, if **(a+b)** is saved in the `x` value of `a`, why is that value not modified again when it does the (a+b) **+c** ?

Comment: `r = a+b+c` is equivalent to `temp = a + b; r = temp + c`. The first statement changes a.x to a.x + b.c and populates temp.x with the same value. The second statement sets temp.x to temp.x + c.x and returns another temporary with the same value (in r.x here). Once the full a+b+c statement is complete, temp no longer exists, so you can't see that it's x has indeed been modified. If you ran the flattened code above, you would see that temp.x was actually equal to a+b+c

Comment: Oh! I get it know. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

The operator+ you coded is actually doing what you would expect from operator+=

operator+ should return an object number holding the computed value, instead of modifying your current object.

Some guidelines [here](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator+` changes `this` because this is the way you defined it.
Alternatively, you may try

```
numbers operator+( const numbers& num ) {
    numbers ret( this->x ); // constract a local copy
    ret.x += num.x;
    return ret;
}
```